# How to set an image URL as error placeholder on Coil in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coil

Coil accepts a drawable resource as an error placeholder. Is there a way to use an image URL here instead?

Here is the code I am working on:

```
// Global variables
var currentlySelectedImageUri = mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null)
var previousImageUri: Uri? = null

// @Composable fun() {...
Image(
    painter = rememberImagePainter(
    if (currentlySelectedImageUri.value != null) { // use the currently selected image
        currentlySelectedImageUri.value
    } else {
        if (previousImageUri != null) { // use the previously selected image
            previousImageUri
        } else {
            R.drawable.blank_profile_picture // use the placeholder image
        }
    }, builder = {
        placeholder(R.drawable.blank_profile_picture)
        error(R.drawable.blank_profile_picture) // FIXME: Set the previously selected image
    }),
    contentDescription = "profile image",
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Coil **2.0.0** both `AsyncImage` and `rememberAsyncImagePainter` have `error` parameter that takes any other painter:

```
AsyncImage(
    model = imageURL,
    contentDescription = null,
    error = painterResource(R.drawable.error)
)
```

---

Coil **1.4.0** version:

You can check `painter.state` value.

Initially it's `ImagePainter.State.Empty`, while image is loading it's `ImagePainter.State.Loading`, and if it failed - it becomes `ImagePainter.State.Error`. At this point you can change coil url, as an example, using local remember variable:

```kotlin
val localImagePainterUrl = remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }
val painter = rememberImagePainter(
    data = localImagePainterUrl.value
        ?: currentlySelectedImageUri.value
        ?: previousImageUri
        ?: R.drawable.blank_profile_picture,
    builder = {
        placeholder(R.drawable.blank_profile_picture)
    })
val isError = painter.state is ImagePainter.State.Error
LaunchedEffect(isError) {
    if (isError) {
        localImagePainterUrl.value = previousImageUri
    }
}

Image(
    painter = painter,
    ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Loved the clean code!! However, it is not providing the expected behavior, although I can't understand why this should not work! :(

Comment: If I provide a valid URL with a non-existing image, it initially shows the blank image, then disappears. It looks like the whole image view gets disappeared, as if I select a valid image next, nothing shows up!

Comment: @Hasan I've checked with local values and it works: put invalid url in `currentlySelectedImageUri` and valid url in `previousImageUri`. Check if local values will work in your case so you know that my part works fine. Also you can add print inside `LaunchedEffect` to check if your request fails, and see which value are you passing to `localImagePainterUrl` at this point

Comment: @Hasan I've tried with valid `currentlySelectedImageUri` - work fine too. Once thing I haven't noticed is that you need to reset `localImagePainterUrl` when your change `currentlySelectedImageUri`, not sure how can I do it if it's a global variable.. But this shouldn't cause the bug you've described

Comment: I think something is going wrong here with recomposition, as it is initially showing the blank profile image after providing a non-existing image URL, and changing that afterward. Can you please have a look at the code here? https://github.com/rawhasan/compose-exercises-image-source

Comment: @Hasan according to your code `currentlySelectedImageUri` should always have the same value as `previousImageUri`. So when you pass there invalid image url, it fails to load it and then falls back to the same invalid url. also storing anything in global variables is for sure not the best practice, consider moving to [view models](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state)

Comment: Thanks, @Philip! I am just temporarily using the global variables. Moving to a view model finally is the plan.

Comment: `previousImageUri` will be different once we provide `currentlySelectedImageUri` a valid URL. What I need is, showing the image in `previousImageUri` when the  `currentlySelectedImageUri` has been supplied an invalid URL or null, instead of the blank image according to my original code. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: My original issue was fixing this line: `error(R.drawable.blank_profile_picture)`. Is there any way to convert an URL to a drawable value?

Comment: @Hasan no, there's no way. that's why I suggested you a solution with local mutable state value

Comment: @Hasan you have error here: https://github.com/rawhasan/compose-exercises-image-source/blob/9e99c6228d8b2fc820431617eeafe193cb42da90/app/src/main/java/com/example/imagesource/MainActivity.kt#L150, you should pass `currentlySelectedImageUri.value` to `previousImageUri`, but your're passing new uri

Comment: Awesome! Working nicely now!! Accepting this as the answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

There is a function inside coil ImageRequest Builder class

```
  fun placeholder(@DrawableRes drawableResId: Int) = apply {
      this.placeholderResId = drawableResId
      this.placeholderDrawable = null
  }
```

Usage:

```
Image(
        painter = rememberImagePainter(
            data = url,
            builder = {
                placeholder(R.drawable.your_placeholder_drawable) // or bitmap
            }
        )
    )
```

**UPDATE**:

Also use: `com.google.accompanist.placeholder`

Dependency gradle: `com.google.accompanist:accompanist-placeholder:accompanist_version`

`// accompanist_version = 0.19.0`

```
Modifier.placeholder(
        visible =  true/false,
        color = color,
        highlight = PlaceholderHighlight.shimmer(color),
        shape = imageShape // RectangleShape)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Will the `placeholder` take an URL as a parameter? - That is my issue. I am currently using the drawable.

Comment: No there is no such a function like you mentioned, but you can load placeholder image get as drawable and set as placeHolder drawable

But what if placeholder can't be loaded? placeholder need to be local I think

Comment: Link for placeholder : https://google.github.io/accompanist/api/placeholder-material3/com.google.accompanist.placeholder.material3/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is an easier way from coil compose api , you can just add  error(R.drawable.your_placeholder_drawable) to the builder and that's it

`Image(painter = rememberImagePainter(data = url, builder = {error(R.drawable.your_placeholder_drawable)}))`