# How to have SubcomposeAsyncImage load a different URL if the first one ended on AsyncImagePainter.State.Error

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I'm  using the pokeApi for my app. Each element has a Sprites object that contain different kinds of images. All have 8-bit-like PNG images (let's call them low-res), but about half of them also have quite better looking SVG images (let's call them hi-res).
I want my grid elements to show hi-res sprites whenever possible, and low-res when the first attempt failed (because the url links to nothing).

I've searched and found this question:
[How to set an image URL as error placeholder on Coil in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68727567/how-to-set-an-image-url-as-error-placeholder-on-coil-in-jetpack-compose)
However, it uses deprecated code that's not compatible with my current code. If I try to use AsyncImage like that question's accepted answer, I lose the SVG rendering - and since it was a successful download, it's just a blank area where the sprite should be. If I try with SubcomposeAsyncImage, I get the SVG allright, but when I scroll to those I know have no SVG sprites I just get blank (because the error state isn't loading the fallback PNG sprite).

Is there an up-to-date way to do what I intend and accomodates both SVG and PNG formats?

[Edit: rephrasing and removing typo]

Comment: If you put `AsyncImage` with the png url into `SubcomposeAsyncImage` error block, it should work, no? Or what's the problem with that? I'm not sure I understand the part "but when I scroll to those I know have no SVG sprites I just get nothing.format" - does that mean that there's no error, but the svg is not loaded either?

Comment: Please see the sprites object in this example of the api: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto.

the front_default goes on PNG, right. But I'm using the elements inside dreamworld, which are SVG and look better. Thing is, only the 649 first pokemon have an SVG, the rest don't. And due to how the "list all pokemon" endpoint works (https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100000&offset=0 ) the URL needs to be calculated using the "id" you can get from the "url" field. 


When that calculated url returns a 404 (error state) I'd like for it to "try again" with a fallback url

Comment: `SubcomposeAsyncImage(model = "primaryUrl", error = { AsyncImage(model = "fallbackUrl") })` should work like that